# How to get the errno of an IOError?

Tags: python, exception, errno, ioerror

C has perror and errno, which print and store the last error encountered. This is convenient when doing file io as I do not have to fstat() every file that fails as an argument to fopen() to present the user with a reason why the call failed.

I was wondering what is the proper way to grab errno when gracefully handling the IOError exception in python?

```
In [1]: fp = open("/notthere")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IOError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)

/home/mugen/ in ()

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/notthere'


In [2]: fp = open("test/testfile")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IOError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)

/home/mugen/ in ()

IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'test/testfile'


In [5]: try:
   ...:     fp = open("nothere")
   ...: except IOError:
   ...:     print "This failed for some reason..."
   ...:     
   ...:     
This failed for some reason...
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The Exception has an `errno` attribute:

```
try:
    fp = open("nothere")
except IOError as e:
    print(e.errno)
    print(e)
```

Answer (score 31):

Here's how you can do it.  Also see the `errno` module and `os.strerror` function for some utilities.

```
import os, errno

try:
    f = open('asdfasdf', 'r')
except IOError as ioex:
    print 'errno:', ioex.errno
    print 'err code:', errno.errorcode[ioex.errno]
    print 'err message:', os.strerror(ioex.errno)
```

- http://docs.python.org/library/errno.html
- http://docs.python.org/library/os.html

For more information on IOError attributes, see the base class EnvironmentError:

- http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html?highlight=ioerror#exceptions.EnvironmentError

Comment: `ioex.strerror` appears to be the equivalent of `os.strerror(ioex.errno)` (python 2.7)

Answer (score 21):

```
try:
    fp = open("nothere")
except IOError as err:
    print err.errno 
    print err.strerror
```

Answer (score 2):

Different exceptions can also be tested for in the same 'except' clause, e.g.

```
try:
    serial_port.open()
except (AttributeError, SerialException) as e:
    print('cannot open serial port: {}'.format(e))
```